# Call Lua from C++ in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua, singleton

I have a classifier model in lua to predict the gender of a person in an image, and I need to call it from C++. I'm using the Lua C API.

I have it working for a single prediction, I mean, in C++ I call **dofile("script.lua")** and the model is loaded from the disk, then I call **predict("image1.jpg")** and I got the result. So far so good.

## Problem

The problem is that I need to be able to call the **predict** function using threads (several at the same time), because the **predict** takes a while to return. 
The model is quite big, so I need to somehow load it once and use it like a singleton.

How can I implement such thing? Or it's not possible / feasible? So far I've tried but none of it worked:

- Having a **model.lua** file with only the model as a singleton and the **script.lua** would get an instance of the model and loading it in the first time. Then in C++, I would have a new **lua_State** and **dofile("script.lua")** every time I need to make a prediction. I tried this but the model was being loaded every time.
- Having a static object **lua_State** in C++ with the **model.lua** always in memory, which would return the model to C++ ( as a table). Then send it to lua to the **script.lua**, like: **predict(model, "image1.jpg")**.
- Similar as the previous one, but instead of returning the model to C++ and send it back to lua, return a callback function to C++, send it back to lua and use it to get the model. Example: **model.lua** has a **getModel()** function which would return the model. I would return the **getModel()** to C++ and send it to the **script.lua**, like: **predict(getModel, "image1.jpg")**. Then the **predict** function would do call **getModel()** to have the model.

## Update

Thanks for the feedback guys. Once it's not possible to implement what I need, I dropped this idea of using the C API to communicate between Lua and C++.

Instead, I'm running a server with Lua - using [luasched](https://github.com/SierraWireless/luasched) , and from C++ I'm creating a new connection to the Lua socket each time I have to make a prediction.

Regards, 
Sérgio

Comment: Load the model and then create thread instances with `lua_newthread` to run `predict` instances?

Comment: Lua is designed for single-threading only. You can have multiple separate Lua VMs though. Or you could make it so the Lua code passes several images to C++, and C++ starts a bunch of threads, classifies the images, stops them and returns the results back to Lua.

Comment: @kfsone A Lua thread is not what Sergio means by a thread.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not generally possible with raw Lua. It is an inherently single-threaded system. While you can create multiple independent `lua_State` objects that can run on independent threads, you *cannot* call into the same `lua_State` instance from two different threads.

You could try [Lua Lanes](http://lualanes.github.io/lanes/), which is ostensibly a threaded framework for Lua. However, it still requires separate `lua_State`s; the main thing it does is (at least in theory) provide a light-weight way to share data between `lua_State`s.

Alternatively, you can create a number of *processes* equal to the number of cores you have. Each process will have to independently load the model, but you will never load the model more times than the number of cores you want to use. But this way, each process can execute any number of `predict` calls. You can even take the filename from stdin, thus allowing some master process to farm out work to an individual process.